# Python uses three unicode characters to represent an asian fullstop? This is weird?

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8

The python file:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

print u"。" 
print [u"。".encode('utf8')]
```

Produces:

```
。
['\xe3\x80\x82']
```

Why does python use 3 characters to store my 1 fullstop? This is really strange, if you print each one out individually, they are all different as well. Any ideas?

Comment: If you want an introduction to unicode, the best one I know is here: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: Just as a matter of interest: what did you _expect_ to see after encoding a unicode string?

Answer (score 7):

In UTF-8, three bytes (not really characters) are used to represent code points between U+07FF and U+FFFF, such as this character, IDEOGRAPHIC FULL STOP (U+3002).

Try dumping the script file with `od -x`. You should find the same three bytes used to represent the character there.

Answer (score 1):

[UTF-8 is a multibyte character representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) so characters that are not ASCII will take up more than one byte.

Answer (score 0):

Looks correctly UTF-8 encoded to me. See [here](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/unicode.html) for an explanation about UTF-8 encoding.

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of Unicode supports more than 109,000 characters in 93 different scripts. Mathematically, the *minimum* number of bytes you'd need to encode that number of code points is 3, since this is 17 bits' worth of information. (Unicode actually reserves a 21-bit range, but this still fits in 3 bytes.) You might therefore reasonably expect *every* character to need 3 bytes in the most straightforward imaginable encoding, in which each character is represented as an integer using the smallest possible whole number of bytes. (In fact, as pointed out by dan04, you need 4 bytes to get all of Unicode's functionality.)

A common data compression technique is to use short tokens to represent frequently-occurring elements, even though this means that infrequently-occurring elements will need longer tokens than they otherwise might. UTF-8 is a Unicode encoding that uses this approach to store text written in English and other European languages in fewer bytes, at the cost of needing more bytes for text written in other languages. In UTF-8, the most common Latin characters need only 1 byte (UTF-8 overlaps with ASCII for the convenience of English users), and other common characters need only 2 bytes. But some characters need 3 or even 4 bytes, which is more than they'd need in a "naive" encoding. The particular character you're asking about needs 3 bytes in UTF-8 by definition.

In UTF-16, it happens, this code point would need only 2 bytes, though other characters will need 4 (there are no 3-byte characters in UTF-16). If you are truly concerned with space efficiency, do as John Machin suggests in his comment and use an encoding that is designed to be maximally space-efficient for your language.

Comment: -1 UTF-8 can require up to **4** bytes. Three bytes covers only the BMP (first 64K codepoints). """and other characters will need only 2 bytes. But some (more, actually, in UTF-8 than otherwise) will still need 3 bytes""" is meaningless. Don't recommend UTF-16; it's effectively a legacy encoding and jumps to **4** bytes after the BMP.

Comment: [continued]  East Asian users will either stick to their legacy encodings (which use only two bytes for their frequent characters), or not worry about the wasted byte, or (if Chinese) use the non-legacy GB18030 (which is a UTF and a superset of earlier encodings and still uses only 2 bytes for frequent characters).

Comment: Thanks for your input, I have learned some more about Unicode and improved my answer.

Comment: You *do* need 4 bytes in order to have an encoding that satisfies (1) support for all 17 Unicode planes (2) ASCII-compatibility, and (3) self-synchronizing.